# react-select does not clear value when redux-form is reset

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I have a stateless React function to render a react-select Select to a form. Everything else works nicely with redux-form except when redux-form is reset. I need to reset the form manually after successful post.

onChange and onBlur change the redux-form value correctly when Select has a value change. When I reset the redux-form, the redux-form value is cleared but the Select will have the old value.

```js
function SelectInput(props) {
  const { input, options, label } = props;    
  const { onChange, onBlur } = input;

  const handleChange = ({ value }) => {
    onChange(value);
  };
  const handleBlur = ({ value }) => {
    onBlur(value);
  };    
  return (
    <FormField {...props}>
      <Select placeholder={label} options={options} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} />
    </FormField>
  );
}
```

I converted the SelectInput to React.PureComponent, and added the value as a state inside the component and looked for when the Component received new props:

```js
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {value: ''}
  }
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ 
   this.setState({value: nextprops.input.value}) 
 }

 <Select value={this.state.value} placeholder={label} options={options} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} />
```

With this Select was not able to show the value at all.

The problem is that how I can update the Select to show empty value  when redux-form that this field is part of is reset? Redux-form resets the value corretly inside the redux state and if I try to submit the form, validation notices that that Select has empty value. The Select will however display the old value so that user thinks that there is a value selected.

Reset is done by dispatching reset in the actual redux-form component. Redux devtools show that fields are reset and the redux state is cleared from all the value, Select component just won't update the DISPLAYED value to empty.

```js
const afterSubmit = (result, dispatch) =>
  dispatch(reset('datainputform'));

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'datainputform',
  onSubmitSuccess: afterSubmit,
})(DataInputForm);
```

Versions I use:

- react-select@v2.0.0-beta.6
- redux-form@7.3.0

Comment: can you include your reset function in the code please?

Comment: Added the reset part from the reduxForm component.

Comment: What is FormField?   We use Field for redux-form, but I've never seen or can find anything on FormField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working. Problem was handling the Select null value. Changed stateless function to PureComponent, added the value to state.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
  }
```

Redux-form changes the react-select value by sending new props. So added

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.input.value === '') {
      this.setState({ value: '' });
    }
  }
```

Added setState to handleChange:

```js
  handleChange = (data) => {
    const value = data === null ? '' : data;
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.input.onChange(data.value);
  };
```

And then added the value prop.

```js
<Select value={this.state.value}...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also set a key at the form level itself. The key will take a unique value that you can store in the component state. This unique value will be updated every time reset is hit.

```
state = {
  unique_key: ''
}

// this is the onClick handler for reset button on the form
onResetForm = () => {
  reset_val = Date.now();
  this.props.reset();
  this.setState({unique_key: reset_val});
}

<Form actions={action_func}, key={this.state.unique_key}/>
```

Now whenever reset is clicked, the handler will update the unique_key. This will result in re-rendering the Form with the default values. The handler also calls the form reset function to clear the redux.

Comment: Works perfectly.