# Clear selected option and show the placeholder after submit form

Tags: javascript, react-select

I have a form which uses react-select and I tried many ways to remove the selected value from the box after submitting the form. I want it to show the placeholder text after a successful submit but I couldn't get it to work. After submitting it is still showing me the option that I chose before submitting. The way that I am showing you here is by setting the state of the react-select value to ''. I also tried setting an empty array, didnt work. Where is the mistake?

This is in my container file

```
import * as downloadedArray from '......the file that have the fixed options'
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
      val: '',
    })
  }

handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
......post to server......
  .then(()=> {
      this.setState({val: ''})
  }   

}

<SelectComponent select_id='select_id' select_options={downloadedArray} select_placeholder='Choose an option' handle_change={this.handleChange} val={this.state.val} />
```

This is my select component in another file

```
const SelectComponent = ({select_id, select_options, handle_change, select_placeholder, val}) => (
  <div className='pl1 pl4-l pl2-m pr1 pr4-l pr-2-m pt1 pt4-l pt2-m pb2 pb3-l'>
    <Select id={select_id} name={select_id} options={select_options} onChange={handle_change} placeholder={select_placeholder} value={val} isClearable />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: did you try `this.setState({val: null})` or `this.setState({val: undefined})`?

Comment: Just did, not working. Still showing the last chosen option.

Comment: @calvert have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640858/react-select-does-not-clear-value-when-redux-form-is-reset ?